# Distribution of items in ordered list with respect to constraints

Tags: optimization

I have a very specific problem and Im desparate for help, I've been working part time on it for almost a year without almost any success, I'll do my best to describe it as thorough as I can

Our input data is an array filled with  objects who have properties time and type. From now on I'll refer to them as "events". Those events are sorted by their time property. The time property refers to the start time of an event. Event duration is from it's start to the start of the next event. Possible event types are "F", "S", "D" and "O". It's important to note that type "F" and "S" dont differ in any way for this stage of the problem.

The goal of a function/algorithm is to manipulate times of events so that multiple constraints(which I'll describe later) are satisfied, and that original order of events is preserved.

About constraints, the constraints are of very specific nature (they are dynamic), and they have been the most confusing part to figure out to all people that I asked for help. We have 4 constraints and all of them work in the same way, but I'll describe them one by one.

First constraint allows for maximum cumulative duration of events with type "D" and "O" of 50 hours. When that limit is reached for a clock to be re-set we need continius cumulative duration of events with type "F" or "S" of at least 30 hours.

Second constraint allows for maximum cumulative duration of events with all types of 10 hours. When that limit is reached for a clock to be re-set we need continius cumulative duration of events with type "F" or "S" of at least 6 hours.

Third constraint allows for maximum cumulative duration of events with type "D" of 8 hours. When that limit is reached for a clock to be re-set we need continius cumulative duration of events with type "F" or "S" of at least 6 hours.

Fourth constraint allows for maximum cumulative duration of events with type "D" of 4 hours. When that limit is reached for a clock to be re-set we need continius cumulative duration of events with type "F" or "S" or "O" of at least 1 hour.

Im willing to do paid consulting with anyone who wants to dedicate their free time for my problem.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "When that limit is reached for a clock to be re-set we need..."  Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: What is meant by "maximum cumulative duration of events"?  Does this refer to a contiguous/consecutive sequence of events of the same type?  Please [edit] your question to explain what you are asking more clearly.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not being specific enough, you should look at constraints like clocks. Events with certain types drain them and events with some other types re-set them if criteria is met.

Comment: @MatijaMilikic, can you give some specific examples?

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it is clear, based on the feedback received.  I still don't understand the answer to any of my questions.  Can you be more specific?  Can you give one example of a single clock, and state precisely under what conditions it increases or decreases, what happens when it reaches zero, and what exactly is the constraint that must be satisfied relating to that clock?  Can you edit your question so the answers to the earlier questions are clear?